# Cannot execute Context.Entity.SqlQuery Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am not able to execute a Raw Sql Where query in Entity framwork.

Model :

```
public partial class Web_User_Setup_Header
{
    public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
    public string User_ID { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Expiration_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Model Entity Configuraiton :

```
public class Web_User_Setup_HeaderConfigruation : EntityTypeConfiguration<Web_User_Setup_Header>
{
    public Web_User_Setup_HeaderConfigruation()
    {
        ToTable("Web User Setup Header");
        HasKey(x => x.User_ID).Property(x => x.User_ID).HasColumnName("User ID");
        Property(x => x.Expiration_Date).HasColumnName("Expiration Date");
    }
}
```

The Sql query which I am executing is :

```
 Web_User_Setup_Header WebSetup = context.Web_User_Setup_Headers.SqlQuery("Select * from [" + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Items["Company"]) +
                 "$Web User Setup Header] where User_ID=@p0", uid).SingleOrDefault();
```

where `HttpContext.Items["Company"] = "Sachin Sales"`

and `uid = "web"`

when i Execute the above query it gives error as : `Invalid column name 'User_ID'.`

When I change `User_ID` to `[User ID]` in the query it gives error as :

`The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'JSTestWeb.Models.Web_User_Setup_Header'. A member of the type, 'User_ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.`

Can someone put some light on this matter? However the Database Field name is `[User ID]` only in Database and I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) to build a dynamic query. But you will need to use the `ObjectContext` API to execute ESQL.

```
public class MyContextTest : DbContext
{
    public virtual ObjectContext UnderlyingObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }
    }
}
```

The query syntax is little bit different from SQL.

```
 Web_User_Setup_Header WebSetup = context.UnderlyingObjectContext
    .CreateQuery<Web_User_Setup_Header>("Select VALUE C from [" +    
     Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Items["Company"]) +
     "$Web User Setup Header] AS C where C.[User ID]=@p0", 
        new ObjectParameter("p0", uid)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: so i cant do `Select * from [" + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Items["Company"]) +
                 "$Web User Setup Header] where User_ID=@p0` directly . Is there any way i can get it working directly ? Btw i tried your solution Its still giving errors :(

Comment: Okay my bad i had to include all columns . But its returning null now . But what if 50 columns are there . Do i have to type all of them :( :( . Now thats something which i wont want from an ORM ? Is there Anyway i can get `Select * from tablename where condition='abc'` staight working in that scenario ? :(